# CSS Eliminate Padding Around Navigation Bar

Tags: css, html, html-lists, navigationbar

I'm trying to create a navigation bar at the top of my page that is flush to the top of the page like this http://mightytext.net/ . However, I always end up with some white padding on the top and sides of the page.

How do I get rid of this padding so that the content lines up directly against the top of the page?

Here is my code:

```
<div id='header'>
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
#nav {
width: 100%;
float: left;
display: block;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
list-style: none;
background-color: #3498DB;
}
#nav li {
float: left;
}
```

Comment: the margin you see is on the body tag. Try adding something like `body { margin: 0; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely need to use a reset style. At a basic level, you can simply add the following rule to the top of your CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
```

But you'd be better using one of the many CSS reset files, such as [HTML5 Reset](http://html5reset.org/) or [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

Comment: This was the first answer that worked, so I'll accept it. I really love the reset site, http://html5reset.org/ , that you included. Thanks for that :).

Answer (score 2):

```
html, body { margin:0; padding:0 }
```

A good way to avoid such situation is by using CSS resets, like the one [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/)

Answer (score 0):

You can always try using negative pixels!

```
#nav {
width: 100%;
float: left;
display: block;
margin: -1px;
padding: 0px;
list-style: none;
background-color: #3498DB;
}
```